# jQuery plot has percentage symbol on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using jQuery Flot plugin to draw some graphs. On my local environment everything works fine, but on a test server when i hover over a dot from the graph it yields `My_text_label: %y`.

In place of `%y` I expect the y-coordinates of that point.

Here is my code sample:

```
data = [{
    label: label,
    data: d1,
    color: "#48CFAD"
}];

Options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time"
    },
    yaxis: {

    },
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            fill: false,
            lineWidth: 2
        },
        points: {
            show: true,
            radius: 4.5,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: "#ffffff",
            lineWidth: 2
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: false,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    legend: {
        container: legend,
        show: true
    },

    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: '%s: %y'
    }

};

$.plot(holder, data, Options );
```

Comment: Seems like a strange problem. Do you use the same version of the plugin in both environments? Could you give a link to the testserver if it is public?

Comment: i can't is private, and yes are the, have same git repository

Comment: I fear we cannot find the difference then. It should work fine as it is. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kekf0bky/).

Comment: Can you see what your document mode is for your browser?  If you have a meta tag that forces an earlier document mode in the environment where this functionality doesn't work, this may be the cause.  In particular, if the tooltip plugin uses `indexOf` to find and replace the "%y" and your document mode does not support `indexOf`, then that may be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the dot the `tooltipOpts:` is called and it displays the `content: '%s: %y'`

`%s` reads as `My_text_label`

`:` is read as `:`

`%y` is read as `%y`

As you stated, it doesn't work on the test server but works fine locally.  The problem could be that your version of JQuery on your local machine is different to the version on the test server.

Comment: `%y` reads as the y value of the datapoint normally. And as the question states, it works on one machine but not the other. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh, in that case could the OP check if their JQuery versions are the same on both their local machine and test server?

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with Flot graphs behaving differently in two different environments.  My issue was that, in the production environment, jQuery was getting reloaded after my Flot script tag was being called.  Since the Flot plugins were "attached" to the jQuery variable, the Flot functionality was getting overwritten.  For example, I could no longer call `$.plot` since the jQuery variable had been redefined.

I ended up having to use the `$.getScript` function to reload all the Flot code(including plugins) before calling `$.plot` after the page renders(and the Flot functionality has been overwritten).

In your case, since you are using a plugin, I am not sure how you could solve this effectively.  I have not tested it, but try using something like

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    // add $.getScript calls here
});
```

to load your Flot js files and plugins.